# Read and write data from server

Tags: android, mysql, database

I want to read and write data on my server database from android UI.

I have a host which has MySQL.

any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1):

Create php to create json for your data on the server.

Use RoboSpice for aysnc loading your json via the network.

See https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

Comment: it's reading feature. How about writing something to server, any suggestion ??

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you only need some data storage you do not need your own server. Take a look at services like Plamo (www.plamo.nl) with data storage json apis.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) is your friend. On server side you should create php pages (or another ones) and make requests from your app to these pages.